# How to know whether an indoor plant has outgrown its pot?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, repotting

I have Dieffenbachia, Money plant, Snake plant.

What are the signs I should look for to know whether they have outgrown their pot or not?

Answer (score 6):

Here are some diagnostics but the best way is the first one:

- Once a year take the plant out of its pot.  If all you see is roots circling around then cut an inch or two (2 - 4 cm) from the bottom of the root ball, add more soil to the pot and put the plant and root ball back in. Water thoroughly
- when watered the soil becomes dry quickly. Some water sensitive plants like spathiphyllum or peace lily can require more water only days later.
- little or no new growth
- depending on species you might see fine hair roots all over the surface

Snake plants (Sanseveria) tolerate being in the same pot much longer than other plants. I would not rush to repot this.

Comment: Excellent answer Kevinsky...HANDS ON to understand plants.  Really excellent.